# Relative URL with Extensionless URL Routing

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-routing, asp.net-4.0

I new to URL routing, but I'm planning out how it will work so I can have a URL like `products.aspx?category=cars` appear as `products/cars`.

Biggest problem I can see happening is that if have a link to `products.aspx?category=food`  on a page with a rerouted URL wouldn't the browser send the user to `products/cars/products.aspx?category=food`?

Am I wrong or is there a way to get around this?

Comment: What do you mean when you say ajax call? Surely an ajax call would be to a .asmx/.svc? Are you asking how to resolve hrefs correctly on your products/cars page?

Comment: @Jon [no](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+page+method). I rephrased the question to make it more generic

Comment: Here's a how-to with URL rewrite: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/461/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will send it to products/cars/products.aspx?category=food, correct.

You can solve this by adding a preceeding '/' to your url so it becomes /products.aspx?category=food

However if you're URL mapping won't you want to build your links as "products/food" so that they can be rewritten?

Answer (score 0):

What you are after is URL Rewriting or Friendly URLS.  Heres a link that might help for ASP.NET I do not use NET myself so not sure

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18318/URL-Mapping-URL-Rewriting-Search-Engine-Friendly-U

But this might help:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine

Answer (score 0):

Typically, with URL rewriting, you are always going to be using index.aspx. All of your paths will be setup with a pattern you establish.

index.aspx?display=products&category=food

would turn into

mysite.com/products/food 
or
mysite.com/products/category/food

You are able to customize how you handle this with configuration options with your particular rewriting tool.